# How to make a Binary Search Tree a Complete Binary Search Tree in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

**The accepted answer can make a Perfect tree (which is also a Complete tree). Although it cannot make a Complete tree without being Perfect. It was the closest answer to my request though. To make a compete the without being Perfect too, you could remove the rightmost leaves of the tree.**

**1. Problem:**

Trying to make a `Binary Search Tree` into a `Complete Binary Search Tree`. I can find lots of code examples for a `Complete Binary Tree`, but no `Complete Binary Search Tree`. The insert is working as a Binary Search Tree should. But this way of inserting is not a Complete Tree. If I add a bunch of random numbers, it will not be a Complete tree. How can I make the code insert to the tree **but** at the same time be a complete binary search tree?

I would greatly appreciate a code example. I don't find it hard to understand it in theory at all, but very hard to implement it in code.

**2. What I tried:**

- To add the nodes in a level order way.
- While loop "Insert as long as the height is not 6 and all nodes are full nodes except leaves".
- "Add only to the right child if the value is greater than the parent and if the left child is not null".
- `Arrays` and `LinkedLists` to add from.

**3. How I insert:**

```
private BinaryNode<AnyType> insert( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
{
    if( t == null )
        return new BinaryNode<>( x, null, null);

    int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

        if (compareResult < 0)
            t.left = insert(x, t.left);
        else if (compareResult > 0)
            t.right = insert(x, t.right);
        else
            ;  // Duplicate; do nothing

    return t;
}
```

- The `AnyType` is the value to be inserted, the `BinaryNode` is the
  current node.

**4. What the program is able to do:**

- Insert and remove.
- Find Height, minimum, maximum or specific node.
- Preorder, Postorder, Levelorder, and Inorder searches.
- Get the number of full nodes, number of all nodes, and number of leaves.

**5. Full program:**

```
import java.nio.BufferUnderflowException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Implements an unbalanced binary search tree.
 * Note that all "matching" is based on the compareTo method.
 * @author Mark Allen Weiss
 */
public class ExerciseBinarySearchTree03<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
{
    /**
     * Construct the tree.
     */
    public ExerciseBinarySearchTree03( )
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void preOrder(){
        System.out.println("\nPre Order ");
        preOrder(root);
    }
    public void postOrder(){

        System.out.println("\nPost Order ");
        postOrder(root);
    }
    public void inOrder(){

        System.out.println("\nIn Order ");
        inOrder(root);
    }
    public void levelOrder(){
        System.out.println("\nLevel Order ");
        levelOrder(root);
    }


    public int numberOfNodes(){
        return numberOfNodes(root);
    }

    public int numberOfFullNodes(){
        return numberOfFullNodes(root);
    }
    public int numberOfLeaves(){
        return numberOfLeaves(root);
    }

    /**
     * Insert into the tree; duplicates are ignored.
     * @param x the item to insert.
     */
    public void insert( AnyType x )
    {
        root = insert( x, root );
    }

    /**
     * Remove from the tree. Nothing is done if x is not found.
     * @param x the item to remove.
     */
    public void remove( AnyType x )
    {
        root = remove( x, root );
    }

    /**
     * Find the smallest item in the tree.
     * @return smallest item or null if empty.
     */
    public AnyType findMin( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            throw new BufferUnderflowException( );
        return findMin( root ).element;
    }

    /**
     * Find the largest item in the tree.
     * @return the largest item of null if empty.
     */
    public AnyType findMax( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            throw new BufferUnderflowException( );
        return findMax( root ).element;
    }

    /**
     * Find an item in the tree.
     * @param x the item to search for.
     * @return true if not found.
     */
    public boolean contains( AnyType x )
    {
        return contains( x, root );
    }

    /**
     * Make the tree logically empty.
     */
    public void makeEmpty( )
    {
        root = null;
    }

    /**
     * Test if the tree is logically empty.
     * @return true if empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty( )
    {
        return root == null;
    }

    /**
     * Print the tree contents in sorted order.
     */
    public void printTree( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            System.out.println( "Empty tree" );
        else
            printTree( root );
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to insert into a subtree.
     * @param x the item to insert.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return the new root of the subtree.
     */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> insert( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return new BinaryNode<>( x, null, null);

        int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

            if (compareResult < 0)
                t.left = insert(x, t.left);
            else if (compareResult > 0)
                t.right = insert(x, t.right);
            else
                ;  // Duplicate; do nothing

        return t;
    }

    /* Given a binary tree, return true if the tree is complete
       else false */
    static boolean isCompleteBT(BinaryNode root)
    {
        // Base Case: An empty tree is complete Binary Tree
        if(root == null)
            return true;

        // Create an empty queue
        Queue<BinaryNode> queue =new LinkedList<>();

        // Create a flag variable which will be set true
        // when a non full node is seen
        boolean flag = false;

        // Do level order traversal using queue.
        queue.add(root);
        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            BinaryNode temp_node = queue.remove();

            /* Check if left child is present*/
            if(temp_node.left != null)
            {
                // If we have seen a non full node, and we see a node
                // with non-empty left child, then the given tree is not
                // a complete Binary Tree
                if(flag == true)
                    return false;

                // Enqueue Left Child
                queue.add(temp_node.left);
            }
            // If this a non-full node, set the flag as true
            else
                flag = true;

            /* Check if right child is present*/
            if(temp_node.right != null)
            {
                // If we have seen a non full node, and we see a node
                // with non-empty right child, then the given tree is not
                // a complete Binary Tree
                if(flag == true)
                    return false;

                // Enqueue Right Child
                queue.add(temp_node.right);

            }
            // If this a non-full node, set the flag as true
            else
                flag = true;
        }
        // If we reach here, then the tree is complete Bianry Tree
        return true;
    }












    /**
     * Internal method to remove from a subtree.
     * @param x the item to remove.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return the new root of the subtree.
     */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> remove( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return t;   // Item not found; do nothing

        int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

        if( compareResult < 0 )
            t.left = remove( x, t.left );
        else if( compareResult > 0 )
            t.right = remove( x, t.right );
        else if( t.left != null && t.right != null ) // Two children
        {
            t.element = findMin( t.right ).element;
            t.right = remove( t.element, t.right );
        }
        else
            t = ( t.left != null ) ? t.left : t.right;
        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find the smallest item in a subtree.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return node containing the smallest item.
     */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return null;
        else if( t.left == null )
            return t;
        return findMin( t.left );
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find the largest item in a subtree.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return node containing the largest item.
     */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMax( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t != null )
            while( t.right != null )
                t = t.right;

        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find an item in a subtree.
     * @param x is item to search for.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return node containing the matched item.
     */
    private boolean contains( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return false;

        int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

        if( compareResult < 0 )
            return contains( x, t.left );
        else if( compareResult > 0 )
            return contains( x, t.right );
        else
            return true;    // Match
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to print a subtree in sorted order.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     */
    private void printTree( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t != null )
        {
            printTree( t.left );
            System.out.println( t.element );
            printTree( t.right );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to compute height of a subtree.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     */
    private int height( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return -1;
        else
            return 1 + Math.max( height( t.left ), height( t.right ) );
    }


    public int height(){
        return height(root);
    }

    private void preOrder(BinaryNode t )
    {
        if (t == null) {
            return;
        }
            System.out.println(t.element + " ");
            preOrder(t.left);
            preOrder(t.right);

    }

    private void postOrder(BinaryNode t){
        if (t == null) {
            return;
        }
            postOrder(t.left);
            postOrder(t.right);
            System.out.println(t.element + " ");

    }

    private void inOrder(BinaryNode t)
    {
        if (t == null) {
            return;
        }
            inOrder(t.left);
            System.out.println(t.element + " ");
            inOrder(t.right);
    }

    private void levelOrder(BinaryNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }

        Queue<BinaryNode> q = new LinkedList<>();

        // Pushing root node into the queue.
        q.add(root);

        // Executing loop till queue becomes
        // empty
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {

            BinaryNode curr = q.poll();
            System.out.print(curr.element + " ");

            // Pushing left child current node
                if (curr.left != null) {
                    q.add(curr.left);
                }

                // Pushing right child current node
                if (curr.right != null) {
                    q.add(curr.right);
                }
            }
    }

    //O(n) for the below three methods.
    private int numberOfNodes(BinaryNode<AnyType> root){
        if ( root == null ) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + numberOfNodes( root.left ) + numberOfNodes( root.right );
    }


    private int numberOfLeaves(BinaryNode<AnyType> t){
        if( t == null ) {
            return 0;
        }
        if( t.left == null && t.right == null ) {

            return 1;
        }
            return numberOfLeaves(t.left) + numberOfLeaves(t.right);
    }

    private int numberOfFullNodes(BinaryNode<AnyType> root){
        if(root==null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(root.left!=null && root.right!=null) {
            return 1 + numberOfFullNodes(root.left) + numberOfFullNodes(root.right);
        }
        return numberOfFullNodes(root.left) + numberOfFullNodes(root.right);
    }


    // Basic node stored in unbalanced binary search trees
    private static class BinaryNode<AnyType>
    {
            // Constructors
        BinaryNode( AnyType theElement )
        {
            this( theElement, null, null );
        }

        BinaryNode( AnyType theElement, BinaryNode<AnyType> lt, BinaryNode<AnyType> rt )
        {
            element  = theElement;
            left     = lt;
            right    = rt;
        }

        AnyType element;            // The data in the node
        BinaryNode<AnyType> left;   // Left child
        BinaryNode<AnyType> right;  // Right child
    }

      /** The tree root. */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> root;


    AnyType[] arr = (AnyType[]) new Integer[7];


    // Test program
    public static void main( String [ ] args ) {
        ExerciseBinarySearchTree03<Integer> bst = new ExerciseBinarySearchTree03<>( );
        final int NUMS = 20;
        final int GAP  =   37;

        System.out.println( "Checking... (no more output means success)" );

        bst.insert(10);

        for( int i = GAP; i != 0; i = ( i + GAP ) % NUMS ) {
            if(i != 10) {
                bst.insert(i);
            }
        }

        for( int i = 1; i < NUMS; i+= 2 )
            bst.remove( i );

        if( NUMS <= 40 )
            bst.printTree( );
        if( bst.findMin( ) != 2 || bst.findMax( ) != NUMS - 2 )
            System.out.println( "FindMin or FindMax error!" );

        for( int i = 2; i < NUMS; i+=2 )
            if( !bst.contains( i ) )
                System.out.println( "Find error1!" );

        for( int i = 1; i < NUMS; i+=2 )
        {
            if( bst.contains( i ) )
                System.out.println( "Find error2!" );
        }

        bst.inOrder();
    }


}
```

Comment: You told us what your tree can do, what CAN'T it do that you want it to do? I am lost because you say you CAN Insert but then show code for your Insert method which would to me, means you think it's incorrect??

Comment: The insert is working as a Binary Search Tree should. But this way of inserting is not a Complete Tree. If I add a bunch of random numbers, it will not be a Complete tree.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you want a complete binary search tree. If you're concerned about efficiency, then you don't really need a complete tree, just a balanced tree. In that case, a [Self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) is what you're looking for. Trying to maintain a complete tree is exceedingly expensive.

Comment: It's an assignment in our course. I don't get why it couldn't just be a complete binary tree, but oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use recursion, I made a new post where I got an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52749727/9899617

Answer (score 0):

If you think a bit, you will see that with the usual insert function the order of the elements determines the shape of the tree.

- if you enter 2,1,3 or 2,3,1 you will get the level 2 complete binary tree.
- if you enter 4,2,6,1,3,5,7 you will get the level 3 complete binary tree.
- if you enter 8,4,12,2,6,11,13,1,3,5,7,9,10,14,15 you will get level 4 complete binary tree.

here a pseudo code that recursively supplies the elements, initial call must be

getMedium( v , 0 , v.lenght)

```
getMedium( array v , start , finish)

     if start == finish
         insert(v[start])
         return 

     insert( v[(finish - start)/2]
     getMedium( array v , start , (finish - start)/2 -1)
     getMedium( array v , (finish - start)/2+1 , finish)
```

Comment: Yes but I don't want to add the correct numbers manually. I want to give a random amount of numbers and then the tree itself should be complete, it's easy to just add the numbers manually and making it complete :) I don't know if that's what you are trying to do with your pseudo code, I don't quite understand it.

Comment: complete binary trees cannot have a random amount of numbers. They contain 2^n-1 elements. The code recursively generates a complete tree given an array of a correct size. It is like the binary search. The element need not be sequential but must be increasing order. There are binary tree operations named left rotations and right rotation that are used AVL trees and red-black trees etc.

Comment: Ah I understand now, thank you :) I am still a bit lost on your code example though. What is start and finish? And where do you check if the node should be added to the left or to the right? Or should I use your code combined with the insert method I have?

Comment: start is the beginning of the array, finish the end, I wrote the first call there

Comment: I tried added your code and it seems to be fine but I have a problem with the start and end being int values while the array itself is AnyType . I have posted what I did at the end of my post. The problem is in the main method not in the get medium method

Comment: start and end is array the index, not values. as you see they are used as indexes

Comment: Yes but what datatype should I put them at in the parameter of the getMedium pethood?

Comment: Actually it is only array of any type. I only gave the pseudo code. Since you are using C++ and class structure it can acess the insert function. You can fill the array and call the function. Of cource with your syntax. As I see, you gave non increasing array.  getMedium designed to run increasing order.

Comment: I am using Java

Comment: What do you mean by it is only array of anytype :)?

Comment: you can design getMedium function to run for any array of objects.

Comment: If I run the new code I showed in my post I will just get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2

Comment: call bst.getMedium(bst.arr, 0, 6);

Comment: Same error, I will see what I can do,  but thanks for your help :)

Comment: @kelalaka: Re: "complete binary trees cannot have a random amount of numbers. They contain 2^n-1 elements": That's not correct; you're thinking of "perfect binary tree". "Complete binary tree" is slightly more permissive. (The standard terminology here is very confusing; for example, { almost complete binary trees } is a subset of { complete binary trees }.)

Comment: @ruakh yes, you are absolutely right. Time to sleep :)